# Syncing a file to the server in a while loop

Tags: java, cmd, sftp, scp

I have a while loop which appends data in a while loop and it closes every time before the end of the loop. Is it possible to sync that file to a server after I close the file and before I end the loop?

```
//--- Pseudocode
while(1){
    writer.append(data1);
    writer.append(,);
    writer.append(data2);
    writer.append(,);
    writer.flush(),
    // --I need to run a command here that lets me sync the file to the server
}
```

Im trying to Runtime.exe() after the flush. Will that be a good idea? Will it cause any delay?

Comment: Sure it is. Give it a try and if you run into problems, come back and show us what you tried and what didn't work. That said, it won't perform very well because server communication is slow, but that's a different story.

Comment: Could you explain your problem better, please? Do you need to run an operating system command, using `Runtime.exec`?

Comment: any suggestions to start with?

Comment: @DaniloPiazzalunga yup! is there any java library that can help with this?

Comment: I would start by google searching for how to transfer a file between servers from Java code, but that's just me.

Comment: Do you want to run the `scp` command to upload your file to a remote server?

Comment: Yup! because i initially used WinSCP using GUI. But that dint work because the while loop was locking the file and WinSCP couldn't sync the data but was just waiting for changes.

Comment: You should really edit your question to add the information you put in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scp", yourfileName, "user@host.example.com:/remote/folder");
Process p = pb.start();
```

But I have not tested this code.

You may run into problems, such as:

- If you are using a password (and not a public key) to authenticate, I don't know if `scp` accepts a password from standard input.

Comment: Thanks Danilo. Will test it. How about server authentication?

Comment: I was just editing the answer. Are you having problem with password authentication? Are you using public key authentication?

Comment: Error: Cannot run program "scp": CreateProcess error = 2 , The system cannot find the file specified

That was the error that I received for 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBUilder("scp","C:/wamp/www/test.csv","user@hostname");

Comment: I believe you should use the full path to `scp`.

Comment: Sorry Danilo but full path to scp as in?

Comment: The full path is, for example: `C:/Program Files/SSH/scp.exe`.